# Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load

Tags: php, html, authentication, soap

For a project, I need to be able to do SOAP requests to a private Microsoft exchange server but I am getting the error presented here.
The website where the "services.wsdl" file is stored needs a login and a password to be accessed.
In the php.ini file, the line "extension=php_openssl.dll" is active.

The full error is :

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing
> WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://_____.fr/ews/services.wsdl'
> : failed to load external entity
> "https://____.fr/ews/services.wsdl" in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Test\SOAP\soap.php:4 Stack trace: #0
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Test\SOAP\soap.php(4):
> SoapClient->__construct('https://...', Array) #1
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Test\index.php(37):
> include_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Test\SOAP\soap.php on line 4

And the code used :

```
$url = "https://******.fr/ews/services.wsdl";
$client = new SoapClient($url, array('login'          => "*******",
                                    'password'       => "*******"));

$client->__getTypes();
$client->__getFunctions();

$result = $client->functionName();
```

Comment: Check if the WSDL endpoint is reachable

Comment: The WSDL endpoint works on SOAP UI.